# showing function to be less than half it's square-real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am solving my problem set and instructor has asked me to show that if $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ with $f'{(x)}\geq x \forall x$.

Then show that $f{(x)}\leq f{(0)}+1/2(x^{2})$  $\forall x\leq0$.

What I have done is that I took first order Taylor series expansion at c=0,

$f(x)\simeq f(0)+f{}'(0)x$

since $f'{(x)}\geq x \forall x$ $\Rightarrow$  $xf'{(0)}\leq 0$ $\forall x\leq0$

$\Rightarrow$  $f{(x)}\leq f{(0)}$

As $1/2(x^{2})\geq0$ $\forall x\leq0$ $\Rightarrow$  $f{(x)}\leq f{(0)} + 1/2(x^{2})$

can someone review this? Is there a better or more concrete way to do this question?
I will be grateful.

Comment: Your proof is wrong. If you take $f(x) = x^2/2$, then $f(x) \le f(0)$ is no longer correct.

Comment: Try to integrate your inequality.

Comment: Per Falcon's idea, you can make use of $$f(0) - f(x) = \int_x^0f'(t)\,dt$$ But there is a flaw: If you are using Riemann or Lebesgue, $f'$ being the derivative of some function is not enough to guarantee it is integrable. However, there is a more powerful third choice for integration. Or you can take the classic route of exploiting the mean value theorem to get around the need to integrate.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSinclair can you please give a hint how to construct a function for the mean value theorem? Thanks a lot.